# Attribute [PXNotPersistable] doesn't exist in version 6.1

Tags: acumatica

I'm upgrading a customization project from version 5.3.2936  to version  6.10.0755.   I've run into an attribute: [PXNotPersistable] which, apparently, no longer exists.  I don't know what this attribute does or if there is a replacement.  It's used to decorate a PXSselectJoin BQL statement.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PXNotPersistable attribute was completely removed from the Acumatica Framework mostly because it was not used anywhere inside Acumatica ERP solution.

Below is the implementation of PXNotPersistableAttribute:

```
public sealed class PXNotPersistableAttribute : PXCacheExtensionAttribute
{
    protected override void AddHandlers(PXCache cache)
    {
        cache.RowPersisting += (sender, args) => args.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

As you might notice, the attribute was quite basic and didn't do much: only prevented modified records of the main data view DAC from beings saved to a database.

Say, you have a custom data view declared as follows for ver. 5.3:

```
[PXNotPersistable]
public PXSelectJoin<MyDacA, 
    LeftJoin<MyDacB, On<MyDacB.someField, Equal<MyDacA.someField>>>> DataView;
```

For ver. 6.1, PXNotPersistableAttribute can be simply replaced with the **MyDacA**_RowPersisting handler (since **MyDacA** is the main DAC for our data view and only changes made to this DAC will be saved to a database):

```
public void MyDacA_RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks much, Ruslan!